# Passing argument to function I don't want to execute immediately

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Sorry if my question seems naive, but I seem not to be able to get a simple answer to my question.
In JavaScript I try something like this:

```
window.onload = init; *// ok, this assigns to the window load event a function that doesn't execute straight away*
// now I define my init()function
function init(){
// say...
alert('Noise!');

/* but here is my dilemma... */
```

Next say I want to assign to an `button.onclick` event a function that only executes when I click the button.
But (!here it is...!) I want to pass arguments to this function from here without causing to execute because it (obviously) has brackets.
Something like:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');

var promptInput = prompt("Name?");
button.onclick = printName(promtInput); // I only want to print name on button click
}

function printName(name){
alert(name);
}
```

So... OK, I know the example is stupid. Simply moving all prompt gathering inside `printName()` function and assign to `button.onclick` a bracketless `printName` function will solve the problem. I know. But, still. Is there a way to pass args to functions you don't want to execute immediately? Or it really is a rule (or 'by definition') you only use functions that await execution when you don't plan to pass args via it?

Or how do you best to this thing otherwise?

Comment: You could use an anonymous function like this: `button.onclick = function () {...};`, or use rather a proper event attach method like [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: Cheers Teemu! How do you attach this event?

Comment: [Functions and function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope). Though Stephen has provided a good answer to this already...

Comment: Actually, forget it (unless you are already typing). I will get the books out on that event listener. I just that I could not find answer to my initial question in the books. Maybe it is one of those things that go without saying

Comment: Thanks for link. Am going through it.

Answer (score 4):

```
button.onclick = function() {
    printName(promptInput);
};
```

Comment: Oohh, that's neet!! Simples! I guess that's what Teemu meant too. Ok, that's a simple way of doing it. So I understand there would be no way I can pass args to it then? (am talking about my function not yours)

Comment: no, you don't have control over what parameters are passed to a click handler. The parameters to the handler function are defined by the javascript standard. (The actual parameter is the event object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

For example:

```
button.onclick = printName.bind(null, promtInput);
```

Comment: So execution of printName will only start on my click just because of the bind()?

Comment: Aha, I see. Nice one, too!

Answer (score 0):

You could put the data that you would normally pass as an argument into some other holding location.  You can either put it in a hidden HTML element, or you can use the sessionStorage API to keep it.  So your code would look like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');

var promptInput = prompt("Name?");
sessionStorage.setItem('MyName', promptInput);

button.onclick = printName; // I only want to print name on button click
}

function printName(){
alert(sessionStorage.getItem('MyName');
}
```

Comment: Do you still keep the brackets in this case here button.onclick = printName(); ?

Comment: No, you don't.  Sorry, but I copy/pasted too fast. :)  I've fixed my post.